# using @ as part of the key in the NSDictionary string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code, however when I tried to get the value out of this dictionary using this key it crashes. When I remove the @, it works just fine. Any idea?

```
[self.replacementFBMsgDictionary_ setValue:profileItem.fbId forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", profileItem.username]];
```

Comment: Which @? Can you update the question with the crashing version of that line too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is, "@" at the beginning of a key has special significance in Key-Value Coding — it's used for collection operators like `@count`. As such, KVC keys cannot begin with that string. So instead of the KVC `setValue:forKey:`, you'll have to use NSDictionary's primitive `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

If `profile.username` is an `NSString`, why are you doing that?  Why not just use that for the key?

```
[self.replacementFBMsgDictionary_ setValue:profileItem.fbId forKey:profileItem.username];
```

Comment: He is using @"@%@", because he has @ sign as the 1st character of the key.